# How to animate a circle inside a square in a SVG (animate a nested svg)?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, nested

please share/help if you can.

I want to make a SVG animation with CSS. I have one SVG that includes a "outer" square and a small circle inside of that square. Think of a dice with one dot.
Now I would like to move only the circle inside the box/square. I dont know and cant find how to do that. I can move the whole SVG but not the "inner" SVG.

Here my Code (the outer ID tag works, but I want the inner ID tag to work // I did include the outer tag only for demo purpose // delete it):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #my-circle {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: transparent;
        position: relative;
        animation-name: LtopRbottom;
        animation-duration: 2s;
    }
    @keyframes LtopRbottom {
      0%   { left:0px; top:0px;}
      100% { left:150px; top:150px;}
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="300" height="300"  style="border:1px solid black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="my-circle">
  <svg >
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="280" height="280" ry="20" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="10"/>
  </svg>

  <svg id="my-circle"> 
    <circle cx="150"cy="150"  r="25" stroke="#0ff" fill="#f0f"/>
   </svg>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you've two elements with the same id value. That's not valid.

Comment: I know and I did say that it was just for showing my problem:.(the outer ID tag works, but I want the inner ID tag to work // I did include the outer tag only for demo purpose // delete it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to nest every SVG element inside a separate SVG element. As Robert mentions, you have duplicate ID's and if you want to animate the circle's position, then animate its positioning attributes (cx and cy). SVG subelements don't have left or top properties.

```css
    #my-circle {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: transparent;
        position: relative;
        animation-name: LtopRbottom;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    @keyframes LtopRbottom {
      0%   { cx:0px; cy:0px;}
      100% { cx:150px; cy:150px;}
    }
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300"  style="border:1px solid black" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="280" height="280" ry="20" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="10"/>
    <circle id="my-circle" cx="150"cy="150"  r="25" stroke="#0ff" fill="#f0f"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: How do I freez the animation on the end? The circle should stay at the endpoint. Found this answere add: animation: LtopRbottom 1.0s forwards; in the id "class"

Comment: Use animation-fill-mode: forwards. (I would recommend reading some tutorials on SVG and CSS animations - I hope you don't mind me observing that these are things you should really know before you tackle DOM animation)